# Haskell extracting from tuples within a list

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm a beginner, any help will be appreciated. My goal is to be able to extract the ratings from any given **Film** as a **Float** so I can then manipulate the data properly, for instance give the "average rating" for a film.

```
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Mark = Int
type Rating = (String, Float)

-- Define Film type here
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [Rating])
```

A typical **Film** looks like

```
("True Lies", "James Cameron", 1994, [("Dave",3), ("Kevin",10), ("Jo",0)])
```

I have tried

```
extractRating :: Film -> [(String, Float)]
extractRating (_, _, _, rating) = rating
```

Then calling the function like this

```
putStrLn (extractRating "True Lies")
```

If it helps you help me here this the error dump

```
haskell.hs:82:21:
Couldn't match type ‘(String, Float)’ with ‘Char’
Expected type: String
  Actual type: [(String, Float)]
In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely
  ‘(extractRating "True Lies")’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (extractRating "True Lies")

haskell.hs:82:35:
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
               with ‘(Title, Director, Year, [Rating])’
Expected type: Film
  Actual type: [Char]
In the first argument of ‘extractRating’, namely ‘"True Lies"’
In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely
  ‘(extractRating "True Lies")’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (extractRating "True Lies")
```

Comment: _**Still**_ that movie database exercise??

Comment: Yeah, still. You'll be getting these posts from others like me annually, consider it a tradition ;)

Comment: You are passing a `String` into the `extractRating` function, which expects a `Film` type as the only argument. Also, `putStrLn` expects a `String`. Maybe you want to use `print` instead?

Comment: Does this exercise require you to use tuples? Because this would be much better suited for a Record type.

Comment: I'm having difficulties putting about any humour for this. This really is a bad question and I don't see an excuse for it. No matter how bad the exercise is, why the heck don't you just fiddle around with GHCi a little till you get it? It's really not that hard.

Comment: @FredJames: Which school is giving this exercise in Haskell?

Comment: @FredJames please tell your instructor to ask students to not post these to SO. This is elementary stuff and it is the job of the school to provide it, not SO.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment, but I highly suggest looking into the data keyword and pattern matching instead of using tuples.

PS: Edited to be a little more helpful. Anyway, the problem I'm seeing is "True Lies." extractRating's input is Film type, when you're giving it a string. A way to approach this problem is instead of having the input be a film, just change it to a string, and find any matches based on the given string to return the rating.

Comment: Well, yes, one should use `data` and pattern matching. But this really doesn't answer the question, nor help the OP with the problem at hand, nor do any good for the problem we're having with these stupid film database questions at the moment. (And FWIW, I'm not even sure I disapprove of that exercise using tuples instead of `data` – it's not good style, but for beginners it seems a reasonable simplification.)

Comment: I was trying to not give too much because it seemed like it was homework, which makes it impossible to change these film database questions anyway.